# Appium and Ruby: iOS tests runs v. slow - switch xpath search strategy to something else

Tags: ruby, xpath, appium, appium-ios

For appium, my iOS tests are running pretty slow. I thought this was an issue with instruments-without-delay. I have followed guides online to get iwd to work(e.g. changing plist etc) but tests are still slow so I'm not sure if iwd is the issue. One suggestion I found was to not use xpath locator strategies but I'm not sure how I would change them to not use xpath. The locator code is:

```
# Search by name or exact text.
value = '//*[@name="' + element_name + '"]'
elements = $driver.find_elements(:xpath, value)

# Search for element containing the text "element_name". Uses xpath.
# iOS searches by name, Android by text.
is_iphone ? (xpath = '//*[contains(@name, "' + element_name + '")]') : (xpath = '//*[contains(@text, "' + element_name + '")]')
```

Is there a way to search for the name/text/label of an element without using xpath? (Especially since appium doesn't support locator strategy by name).

Similarly, is there anything else I can do to speed up the tests?

I am running this on iOS 9.3 simulator and xcode 7.

Comment: Needs more info.. What kind of slowness is it? Is finding element slow or even if element is found the action is slow (ex: each alphabet is typed slowly in a text field)? What are the explicit and implicit wait times? Type of app(web, native) and the html/ code for the elements to try css and other identifiers.

Comment: I believe it is an issue of taking too long to find elements on the screen. I also experienced this with android on the same screens but was able to vastly speed that up by turning off animations. Is there any way I can do that for iOS? The app is native.